# Issue with delete http method in firefox and laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, http-delete

Hi I have an issue in Laravel.
I have a project in Laravel and I'm having issues in Firefox. In Chrome all is working fine.
I have this admin view

```
@foreach ($messages as $message)
    <tr>
      <td>
      <a href="{{ route('messages.show', $message->id) }}">
        {{ $message->id }}
      </a>
      </td>
      <td>{{ $message->nombre }}</td>
      <td>{{ $message->email }}</td>
      <td>{{ $message->mensaje }}</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('messages.edit',$message->id) }}">Editar</a>

        <form style="display:inline" action="{{ route('messages.destroy', $message->id)}} " method="post">
          {!! csrf_field() !!}
          {!! method_field('DELETE') !!}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="button">Eliminar</button>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>

  @endforeach
```

I have a table with two buttons, second button is a form to delete the message. O have added method_field('DELETE')

Here is my routes.

```
Route::get('mensajes', 'MessagesController@index')->name('messages.index');
Route::get('mensajes/create', 'MessagesController@create')->name('messages.create');
Route::post('mensajes', 'MessagesController@store')->name('messages.store');
Route::get('mensajes/{id}', 'MessagesController@show')->name('messages.show');
Route::get('mensajes/{id}/edit', 'MessagesController@edit')->name('messages.edit');
Route::put('mensajes/{id}', 'MessagesController@update')->name('messages.update');
Route::delete('mensajes/{id}', 'MessagesController@destroy')->name('messages.destroy');
```

And here the MessagesController destroy method

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    //borro el mensaje
    //DB::table('messages')->where('id', $id)->delete();
    Message::findOrFail($id)->delete();

    //redirecciono
    return redirect()->route('messages.index');
}
```

In Chrome all works fine and message is deleted. But in Firefox, it redirects to /mensajes/{id} route and the message in shown. It seems in Firefox {!! method_field('DELETE') !!} is not working.
Do anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

If I try to clear as proposed I get this message

```
Route cache cleared!

LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.



at C:\laragon\www\laraweb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:880
    876|      */
    877|     public function prepareForSerialization()
    878|     {
    879|         if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
  > 880|             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
    881|         }
    882|
    883|         $this->compileRoute();
    884|

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Routing\Route::prepareForSerialization()
      C:\laragon\www\laraweb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand.php:62

  2   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand::handle()
      C:\laragon\www\laraweb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:29

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Best regards.

Comment: Blade templates are rendered on the server side, so it is impossible that your browser makes a difference when it comes to rendering. It must be something else.

Comment: like @Namoshek pointed as, blade templates are rendered at server side. yoy can check your rendered pure HTML page in firefox 'Inspect Elements' tab. there are no blades anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no problem in your code just run these commands:

`php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score -1):

This is how html form part is rendered in Firefox. I think the code is ok isn't it?

```
<form style="display:inline" action="http://laraweb.test/mensajes/9 " method="post">
          <input name="_token" value="R88rPYL6WJgEDwQizUiJnzMWwptSWyJmgakGrdZC" type="hidden">
          <input name="_method" value="DELETE" type="hidden">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="button">Eliminar</button>
        </form>
```

Here is an screen shot of the network tab in firefox when I push delete button. It seeems it makes a get request... I don't understand it because I have specified POST method...
[image]

Comment: in the network tab take a look at what happens when the 'Eliminar' button is pressed. and let us know. what is the request_url, request_method etc.

Comment: Please edit your question in future if you want to add additional information. An answer is not suitable for providing further details.